# When can a MemorySessionData object exist outside of the MemorySessionContext?

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

I am looking at a portable heapdump file from IBM WebSpehere 6.1 and understand that MemorySessionContext contains a SessionSimpleHashMap of all the MemorySessionData objects that represent the HttpSession for each user.  My question is this, why do I see MemorySessionData objects in the heap outside of that MemorySessionContext "container"?

Comment: Do they have inbound references or are they roots?  Perhaps they weren't completely GC'ed before the heapdump was taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, the "loose" MSD objects had a GC roots path up to Portal objects, so I am tentatively assuming those are the Portal sessions; either that or they are in the process of being released as they are maybe de-referenced by the container and then set loose ... I didn't check all the path-to-GC-roots.